No text highlight in jupyter cells
I installed jupyter notebook and don't get any text highlighting on my .ipynb files. It seems that it treats the code as plain text, even though the code is executed perfectly.
No text highlight
On the options, one can see that neither "Python" nor "none" is selected. As a matter of fact, I'm not able to select any option at all!
Non-selectable options
However, this problem doesn't occur when I open with Jupyter Lab.
JupyterLab seems fine
Notes: Not using Anaconda. Installed everything using pip in a virtual environment.
Python version 3.12.4
Jupyter Notebook version 7.2.1
JupyterLab version 4.2.3
Refreshing with ctrl + shift + R doesn't work and nothing in the settings seems out of order.
I appreciate any help.
Thanks.

It is called syntax highlighting. Did you try a different browser? Do you have any extension running in your browser? If so, try disabling them. This looks very similar to here, especially since it is fine in JupyterLab. I'm linking each via comments in case one gets a solution. This will lessen chance one thread becomes a silo, separate from reference to the other.

Disabling extensions gave no results.
However, changing the browser form Firefox to Chrome did work.
Thanks!

Interesting. It would probably be a hassle if you rely on your browser to remember settings and passwords, however, I wonder if really fully clearing your browser cache may help? Not suggesting you actually test since you found a work around for now.

I had a similar situation to yours and can verify that clearing the browser cache enabled syntax highlighting in .ipynb files. Interestingly, the "text editor syntax highlighting" options are still greyed out.
My situation (for anybody with a similar issue):

Used Jupyter Notebook through Anaconda (highlighting worked fine).
Uninstalled Anaconda (didn't need it), installed Jupyter Notebook using this tutorial.
Ran Jupyter Notebook from virtual environment and found that highlighting didn't work.
Cleared cache on Firefox and now highlighting works again.


This solved this issue for me with a new install through pip and Chrome.

Clearing the cache alone worked for me. Didn't need to reinstall anything.
